# Stringbuilder to RDD

Tags: scala

I have a string builder(sb) with data as below in Scala IDE

```
CellId,Date,Time,MeasType,MeasResult

251498240,2016-12-02,20:45:00,RRC.ConnEstabAtt.emergency,0

251498240,2016-12-02,20:45:00,RRC.ConnEstabAtt.highPriorityAccess,0

251498240,2016-12-02,20:45:00,RRC.ConnEstabAtt.mt-Access,4
```

Now I want to convert this string into `RDD` by using `scala`. Please help me.

I am using this code. But no luck. Thanks in advance

```
 val headerFile = sc.parallelize(sb)
 headerFile.collect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*StringBuilder* is ***used to build strings from mutable sequence of characters***. So what ever you add to the builder would be appended to become as one string.

You would need to *separate the strings added to be used as list of strings in sparkcontext*

Assuming that the string are added with trailing line feed, you can split the string builder with line feed and use it to be transformed as `rdd`

```
val headerFile = sc.parallelize(sb.toString.split("\n"))
headerFile.collect()
```

To visualize the data, you would have to print them or save them to file

Now if you want to convert to dataframe before saving then you can perform as below

```
val data = sb.toString.split("\n")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(data.head.split(",").map(StructField(_, StringType, true)))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(sb.toString.split("\n").tail.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(","))))
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+
|CellId   |Date      |Time    |MeasType                           |MeasResult|
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+
|251498240|2016-12-02|20:45:00|RRC.ConnEstabAtt.emergency         |0         |
|251498240|2016-12-02|20:45:00|RRC.ConnEstabAtt.highPriorityAccess|0         |
|251498240|2016-12-02|20:45:00|RRC.ConnEstabAtt.mt-Access         |4         |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to append after each item of loop sb.append("\n"). and used same as u suggested, But still cannot see any records in RDD.

Comment: and also If i run headerFile.saveAsTextFile("out\\string\\test"). I am getting file with data in given path. Only when I am using collect() inside the program its not showing

Comment: collect wouldn't show the records. collect is for collecting all the rdds distributed in a clustered to be collected in the driver . you will have to print them or save them to a file then only you would be able to see

Comment: Thanks its working as you per your suggestion and able to print rdd. Can i convert this into data frame without saving in drive. As I need some do build logic before HDFS transfer

Comment: my pleasure @user3128960 someday you can help me too when time comes ;)